# GNU Make Pattern rules on Windows

Tags: windows, make

I am interested in using GNU Make on Windows. I created a tiny Makefile using a Pattern Rule:

```
all: abcd.o

%.o : %.c
    echo hi
```

However, when I attempt to make all,

```
D:\test>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make" -f Makefile.txt
make: *** No rule to make target `abcd.o', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

I install GNU Make from [this repository](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) that I found describes that this Makefile should work.

```
D:\test>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make" --version
GNU Make 3.81
```

How can I use pattern rules in GNU Makefiles on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### make: *** No rule to make target `abcd.o', needed by`all'.  Stop.

Your makefile contains:

```
all: abcd.o

%.o : %.c
    echo hi
```

This will only work if a file `abcd.c` exists or can be made (by another rule).

---

> Thus, a rule of the form
>
> `%.o : %.c ; recipe…`
>
> specifies how to make a file n.o, **with another file n.c as its
>   prerequisite, provided that n.c exists or can be made**.

Source [10.5.1 Introduction to Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [A Simple Makefile Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) - contains some simple complete makefile examples.

Answer (score -1):

The file abcd.c needs to exist.

Comment: Close finish with @DavidPostill, but your answer doesn't answer the complete extent of the original question.